# How can I remove text between 2 strings in Unix

Tags: unix

Using UNIX commands, how do I reach my desired output that will shorten the postcode to just the first part?

I have tried `sed` command but can't get it to work.

**Input:**

```
"970000","SW3 2BZ","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"280000","SW5 9JZ","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"103000","CF35 3BG","S","N","F","RUMNEY"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"970000","SW3","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"280000","SW5","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"103000","CF35","S","N","F","RUMNEY"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
With sed:

```
sed 's/ [^"]*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/ [^"]*/,"",$2)}1' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file
"970000","SW3 2BZ","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"280000","SW5 9JZ","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"103000","CF35 3BG","S","N","F","RUMNEY"
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub(/ [^"]*/,"",$2)}1' file
"970000","SW3","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"280000","SW5","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"103000","CF35","S","N","F","RUMNEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"ABC","DEF EFG",123' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{split($2,a,"   ");$2=a[1];print}'
"ABC","DEF,123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/ .{3]/,"")}1' file

"970000","SW3","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"280000","SW5","F","N","L","","LONDON"
"103000","CF35","S","N","F","RUMNEY"
```

removes space and next 3 characters